# Is it unethical to return property in a way that most benefits myself?

Tags: ethics

Lets say I found a USB drive with a biotech companies data. Is it unethical to return the property in the way I believe benefits me the most like by tweeting the company?

If I'm unable to discern or contact the actual owner, Who would most likely want me to return the USB discreetly, am I justified in seeking a more public methodology of returning the property?

update: I emailed the owner no response in 24 hours. Emailed the company's email no response in 6~ hours called them no response. Sent a tweet to them, no response in 24 hours.(I'm not verified so literally 7 people saw the tweet in 24 hours). I deleted the tweet and drove to their office and gave it to the person at the front desk.

Comment: It could harm the person responsible for the loss more, than if you returned it discreetly, right?

Comment: Yes possibly but if it takes longer to return it may make them look even more incompetent/unreliable or dishonest by not mentioning the possible loss sooner.

Comment: Doing something to help yourself is not unethical. Doing something to hurt somebody else may well be. While you are there with a found-USB, keep in mind there is a non-trivial chance it's a "phish" attack.

Comment: Noted, if I found it near a place of work that might be the case. It seems legit though.

Comment: You are.bot specific enough. What do you mean benefits YOU. Why do you NEED TO BENEFIT instead of just returning the USB? If you can tweet the company that tells me you know how to contact them & look up the addresses. Why not just do that? They do not need to know who you are. I am answering from the view of NORMATIVE ETHICS. This also goes by the name MORTALITY. The other types of so called moral theories or psuedo theories related to Psychology to make MORALITY seen subjective instead of absolute. You are doing too much in this scenario. This goes beyond just doing what is honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example in the question did not actually include any examples of benefitting yourself.

There ARE ways to benefit oneself while doing something like this -- self publicity on Tic-Tok, contacting the company and asking for a reward, etc.  In general, self aggrandizement is frowned upon morally, but is only condemned when you are doing appreciable harm to others.  The Tic Tok or reward request are smarmy, which would be frowned upon by Virtue ethics, but would be simply ignored by rights or utility ethics.

You seemed to be interested in whether to return to the company, as opposed to the individual.  You cannot know how embarrassed the owner will be at work by a public return - it may be significant; it may be minor.  The pragmatic answer would be -- try to find the owner, and if that does not work in a day or two, drop off with the company.  This is not guaranteed to cause the least harm, but it strikes me at least as the solution with the best odds of minimizing harm.  The owner may well be anxiously sweating the loss of the data stick, perhaps to the point of suicide?  And the company may need to protect itself, if the data has actually been compromised, even if they get the stick back.  There are enough "what if" options where returning the stick soon to the company has benefits, that I would advise a rapid drop off if the individual search fails.